# reactstrap 8 (bootstrap4) : how to align items side by side with less column gap

Tags: reactstrap

I am trying to align things side by side using reactstrap

```
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>Text1</Col>
        <Col>Text2</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
```

What i want is

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-banach-wep37?file=/src/App.js:740-847

I tried

```
    <Container>
      <Row md="auto">
        <Col>Text1</Col>
        <Col>Text2</Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
```

BUt nothing changes
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rrH2.png

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: They are side by side

Comment: Sorry I mean, The col gap i dont want

Comment: You can remove gutters by `<Row noGutters={true}>`